# Let $f \in O(D)$ for some domain $D$. Prove that if $|f(z)|$ is a constant, then $f(z) =$ const on $D$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f \in O(D)$ for some domain $D$. Prove that if $|f(z)|$ is a
constant, then $f(z) =$ const on $D$.

---

It seems to me it is the direct application of the following version of maximum modulus principle:

> Let f be a function holomorphic on some connected open subset $D$ of
>   the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ and taking complex values. If $z_0$ is
>   a point in $D$ such that
>
> $|f(z_0)|\ge |f(z)|$ for all z in a neighborhood of $z_0$, then the
>   function f is constant on D.

Comment: The symbol $O(D)$ means ring of holomorphic functions on $D,$ I guess. Then as you have mentioned, it is a direct corollary of maximum modulus principle.

Comment: You can also derive that directly from the Cauchy-Riemann equations, without using the maximum modulus principle, compare http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244342/if-the-absolute-value-of-an-analytic-function-f-is-a-constant-must-f-be-a-c.